# BindAttribute does not fiter properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I only want to validate the Name property, so I use Bind, but when I execute the ValidateName action, the response is "Incorrect"

This is my query:

```
http://localhost/api/values/ValidateName?Name=John
```

Why it returns me an "Incorrect" if I filter with Bind?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ValidateName([Bind("Name")] User user)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return Ok( "Valid" );
     }
     else
     {
          return NotFound( "Incorrect" );
     }
}

public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the ModelState errors to see why?

Comment: @Scrobi: Obvoiusly, cause `Id` is empty, because only name is bound to the model

Comment: @Tseng, my point was just to see what they had done for themselves first. and hopefully apply those problem solving skills in the future when they have similar issues. Maybe I should have been descriptive on how to check for the error.

Comment: `Bind` implies that the server is only going to receive the fields/parameters that you include in the `Bind`. However, your user model requires that you have both `Id` and `name` present in the model for it to be valid. Thus, you are getting the error. Also if your `Id` is required it should not be nullable (`int?`)

Answer (score 2):

Bind is not there for filtering, but for binding.

Validator will always validate all properties of your model. Create two distinct ViewModels and use these instead.

```
public class UserNameViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And **most important**: Don't use your persistence models as input or output of your controllers, always use some ViewModel or Binding models, then map to your persistence models in code.

Or in your simplified case, just use a get or post parameter w/o a model:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ValidateName([FromQuery] string username)
{
     if(/* some validation here */)
     {
          return Ok( "Valid" );
     }
     else
     {
          return NotFound( "Incorrect" );
     }
}
```